# Автоматическое включение Android телефона при подключении зарядки

Tags: android, файловая-система, root

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть телефон, из которого я хотел бы сделать видео-регистратор для моего автомобиля. Програмку то написал, которая будет видео записывать, сохранять и т.д. Но как сделать так, чтобы телефон включался при подключении USB-зарядки, провод которой вставлен в розетку 220B?

ROOT доступ полный. Модель телефона - `ZTE Blade Q Lux 3G PRO`. Android 4.4.2.

В интернете читал статьи как это сделать на телефонах `Samsung`. Как сказано [тут](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=449574) в одном из ответов, необходимо изменить содержимое файлов `/system/bin/playlpm` или `/system/bin/lpm`, но ни того, ни другого файла в моём телефоне не существует. Насколько я понял принцип, надо найти файл, который запускает анимацию батарейки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и добавить строчки включения системы:

> #!/system/bin/sh
>
> /system/bin/reboot

Пробовал менять всё содержимое на эти строки в следующих файлах:

- /system/bin/bootanimation
- /system/bin/ipod
- /system/bin/chcon

Безрезультатно. Может какие-то другие файлы надо изменить? Или вообще в другой папке копаться надо? Подскажите.

---

Когда попробовал проделать такой трюк с файлом `/system/bin/chcon` у меня перестала работать кнопка отключения дисплея. То есть, короче, как я включил телефон, так дисплей и работает, не отключается и не реагирует на кнопку выключения. Только после восстановления прежнего файла всё стало нормально после перезагрузки телефона. Так что делаю вывод, что автоматическое включение реализовать возможно. Каждый системный файл действительно запускает скрипты, каждый свой, и отвечает каждый сам за себя. Необходимо лишь понять где нужный файл анимации заряда батареи телефона и где в нём именно надо вписать команду включения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для того, чтобы телефон запускался при подключении зарядки необходимо выполнить следующие действия.

- Скачать и установить на компьютер программу Adb Run. Она необходима для установки соединения с телефоном по USB-проводу.
- Скачать и установить на компьютер программу Bootimg. Она необходима для редактирования файла `boot.img` прошивки телефона. Патч программы должен быть `C:\Users\Admin\`.
- Скачать прошивку (ZIP-архив) на компьютер. Из архива достать файл `boot.img` и положить в папку с программой Bootimg. Открыть системную консоль (Меню пуск -> cmd). Ввести следующую команду:

  ```
  bootimg --unpack-bootimg
  ```

Открыть создавшуюся папку `initrd`, найти в ней файлы `init.rc` и `init.charging.rc`. Открыть их. В каждом из них находим строки:

```
service ipod /system/bin/ipod
    user root
    group root
```

и после них ниже пишем:

```
    class_start core
    class_start main
    class_start default
```

Сохраняем и закрываем оба файла. Возвращаемся в консоль. Пишем следующую команду:

```
bootimg --repack-bootimg
```

Запускаем программу Adb Run. По умолчанию она устанавливается в `C:\adb\`. 
Выбираем пункт 5, затем 0. Телефон должен войти в режим Fastboot. Затем выбираем пункт 1, и затем 1. В консоли должны отобразится как минимум две строки:

```
List of devices attached
0123456789ABCDEF    device
```

Если вы видите только это:

```
List of devices attached
```

то у Вас могут быть следующие ошибки:

- Не включена [отладка USB в режиме разработчика](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj03Pfj-YvOAhWH3CwKHZavCssQtwIIIjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DDLvT3i-qEXs&usg=AFQjCNHCmAy4s0kl5j4NUewyioJVgdV6jA&sig2=8nvaqTyU77U-fG_B35jI4A&bvm=bv.127984354,d.bGg)
- Некорректно подключён USB-провод или, возможно, повреждён
- В диспетчере устройств (Правой кнопкой мыши по ярлыку "Мой компьютер"; Свойства; Диспетчер устройств) телефон отображается как неизвестное устройство, например, как на скриншоте [здесь](http://cs5-2.4pda.to/8435090/Screenshot.jpg?s=005cf429bcf403685794a174000000006e29bf0c5957da94528cd6a5aa7d9dc4)

Затем выбираем пункт 5, затем 0. Ждём, когда на экране телефона появится надпись `FASTBOOT mode..` или что-то наподобие. Выбираем пункт 7, затем 1, и затем пишем:

```
fastboot flash boot C:\Users\Admin\boot-new.img
```

Ждём, когда в консоли появится надпись `Done...` в конце в случае успешной установки `boot.img`. Затем опять пишем в консоли:

```
fastboot reboot
```

Закрываем программу Adb Run (консоль). Отключаем телефон от компьютера. После загрузки телефона выключаем его. Подключаем телефон к зарядке 220В, и, в течение 10 секунд телефон сам включится. На этом всё готово.

Если у Вас произошли какие-то ошибки или что-то пошло не так, я прошу написать в комментариях. Буду рад помочь!

---

Я хочу ещё дать людям совет: Если с первой попытки выполнить процедуру не получилось по какой-либо причине, попробуйте ещё несколько раз внимательно выполнить все выше перечисленные действия.

---

Если версия Android - 4.4 и выше, то могут возникнуть ошибки и, возможно, ничего не получится. Как мне, например, ответила поддержка корпорации ZTE на вопрос "возможно ли хоть как-то реализовать автовключение телефона при..." мне ответили, что видите ли на данном лаунчере такая функция недоступна. И я понял, что решить проблему можно лишь откатом версии Android с 4.4 на 4.2.

Comment: Что-то не смог найти программу Bootimg. Не поделитесь ссылкой?

Comment: Сейчас сам что-то не могу найти. У меня она сейчас есть на компе. Но я вот не могу сюда файл прикрепить. Постараюсь в ближайшее время всё-таки поискать её в интернете.

Comment: Спасибо. Быть может на мыло? 89050011100 собака майл точк ру

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно помню, такая фишка зависит от загрузчика, типа TWRP.
Но в старых версиях при подключении usb-зарядки, загрузка начинается и заканчивается только на самом загрузчике. Чтобы запустить далее андройд, нужно вручную выбрать пункт system reboot. Покопайте в этом направлении.

Comment: Возможно. TWRP не подошёл, так как в Android приложении TWRP в списке поддерживаемых девайсов моего нет. Я пользовался adb (см. ответ выше).